# Creating list of images in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a working code where tkinter application fetches a GIF file and displays it on clicking a button
It is working fine for a single GIF image.

What I want is to have an additional button for <kbd>Next image</kbd> and when I click on it, it should display next image. How can I create list of images?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class MyLabel(Label):

    def __init__(self, master, filename):

        im = Image.open(filename)
        seq =  []
        try:
            while 1:
                seq.append(im.copy())
                im.seek(len(seq)) # skip to next frame
        except EOFError:
            pass # we're done

        try:
            self.delay = im.info['duration']
        except KeyError:
            self.delay = 100

        first = seq[0].convert('RGBA')
        self.frames = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(first)]

        Label.__init__(self, master, image=self.frames[0])

        temp = seq[0]
        for image in seq[1:]:
            temp.paste(image)
            frame = temp.convert('RGBA')
            self.frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame))

        self.idx = 0

        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)
        self.button = Button(text="Zoom out",command=self.play)
        self.button.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)


    def play(self):
        self.config(image=self.frames[self.idx])
        self.idx += 1
        if self.idx == len(self.frames):
            self.idx = 0
        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)


root = Tk()


def stop_it():
   anim.after_cancel(anim.cancel)

anim = MyLabel(root,'A.gif')
anim.pack()

stop_it()
root.mainloop()
```

My idea is if I can use below sort of code:

```
images = ['A.gif','B.gif']
images = iter(images)
img = next(images)
```

But how I can implement this in my current code?

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation.

Comment: Have you done any research? There are several questions on this site about displaying lists of images.

Comment: @TheLizzard : Done, Sir

Comment: @BryanOakley : Yes, I did. However, I failed. Logic in this code is little different and I am unable to implement it in my code.

Comment: You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are many ways for making a list of images , but I would make it like this :

```py
# images 
img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("a.gif"))
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("b.gif"))
img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("c.gif"))

# a list of images 
Image_list = [img1 , img2 , img3 ]
```

For iterating I would make something like a counter

```py
counter = len(Image_list)

img_panel = Label(root , image = Image_list[counter] ) 
img_panel.pack()

def next_image():
    counter-=1
    img_panel = Label(root , image = Image_list[counter] ) 
    img_panel.pack()

next_image = Button(root , text= "next image" , command =next_image)
next_image.pack()
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. However, I am still struggling to blend it in my code :(